# Pandas: how to assign a label to each group of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say that I have a `df` like this:

```
   Value
0  True 
1  True
2  False
3  False
4  False
5  True
6  True
7  False
8  True
9  True
```

And say that I want to assign each group of `True` values a label, such that consecutive `True` values are assigned the same label because they constitute a cluster, whereas `False` values get always `0`:

```
   Value  Label
0  True   1
1  True   1
2  False  0
3  False  0
4  False  0
5  True   2
6  True   2
7  False  0
8  True   3
9  True   3
```

How could I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach that is fully independent of the index:

```
m = df['Value']
df['Label'] = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum().where(m)//2+df['Value'].iloc[0]
```

Explanation: if successive values are different, start a new group, keep only the True groups, divide the group number by two to account for the alternating True/False and correct the initial group number depending on whether the first item is False or True.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
>>> df['Label'] = df[df['Value']].index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum()
>>> df
   Value  Label
0   True    1.0
1   True    1.0
2  False    NaN
3  False    NaN
4  False    NaN
5   True    2.0
6   True    2.0
7  False    NaN
8   True    3.0
9   True    3.0
>>>
```

Comment: That's very useful, thanks. Would you mind breaking down and explaining what that one-liner does?

Comment: @Zizzipupp Ah! It filters where `Value` is `True` and cumulatively sums the booleans of whether there are consecutive `True` values. Since `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm seeing that this snippet does not assign the same label to all components of a single cluster, but assigns them a progressive label. So, for the sequence [False,True,True,False,True,True] you have [0,1,2,0,3,4] instead of [0,1,1,0,2,2]

Comment: @Zizzipupp It works for me... You've must of tested it wrong...

Comment: @Zizzipupp It doesn't work?

Comment: @U12-Forward works fine for the the sequence mentioned by OP in comment, don't know what's going wrong at his end